# Matrices, Vectors and Notation

Tags: matrices, notation, scientific-notation

Let a matrix $\mathbf{G}$ be a function of a vector $\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}$:
$$ \mathbf{G} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2\end{bmatrix}.$$

I believe it is valid to notate $\mathbf{G}$ as $\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x})$ since
$$ \mathbf{G} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2\end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf{x}^T} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} +  
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2\end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf{x}^T} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Now consider a matrix $\mathbf{H}$, a function of vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}=\begin{bmatrix}y_1 \\ y_2\end{bmatrix}$:
$$\mathbf{H} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1y_1 & x_1x_2\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} \\ \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_2} & x_2\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_2}\end{bmatrix}.$$

**Question 1**: Is it valid to notate the matrix $\mathbf{H}$ as

(i) $\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})$, without any indication of the partial derivatives in it?

(ii) $\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{x})$?

(iii) Would either notation in part (i) or (ii) be valid if $\mathbf{H}$ is clearly defined, as in the equation above?

**Question 2**: For a more generalized case, where we have $\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n\end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{y}=\begin{bmatrix}y_1 & y_2 & \cdots & y_n\end{bmatrix}$, and numerous cross partial derivative and nonlinear terms in a matrix, what would be a valid notation?

Comment: A linear map can be described by a matrix and a matrix describes a linear map.  They are officially distinct objects of different types.  That is not to say that what you are asking for permission to do is never done... but it is an abuse of notation and you are overloading your symbol "$\textbf{G}$" and "$\textbf{H}$" to mean multiple things at once.

Comment: Option (ii), $\mathbf H( \mathbf x)$ , is correct. I would not call $\mathbf y$ a "vector"; rather, I would call it a "vector-valued function". I would also call $\mathbf H$ a "matrix-valued function" rather than just a matrix. The function $\mathbf H$ takes as input a vector $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^2$ and returns as output the $2 \times 2$ matrix you've written.